# Two nilmanifolds of the same Lie group

Tags: gn.general-topology, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

By a *nilmanifold* I mean a quotient $M =\Gamma \backslash G$ of a connected, simply-connected nilpotent real Lie group $G$ by the left action of a maximal lattice , i.e. a discrete cocompact subgroup.

Suppose we have two  maximal lattices $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ of $G$. What can be said about the nilmanifolds $\Gamma_1 \backslash G$ and $\Gamma_2 \backslash G$? Are they homeomorphic? Or perphaps one is a covering space of the other?

Comment: In general, they are not homeomorphic, and  one is not a covering space of the other. I guess it should be a nilmanifold which admits two finite covers homeomorphic to the given two.

Comment: maximal lattice" is a strange assumption: no nontrivial simply connected nilpotent Lie group $G$ admits a maximal lattice. This is quite obvious in the abelian case (e.g., $G=\mathbf{R}$). In the general case, if $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $G$ and $Z$ is the center of $G$ (which is nontrivial), then $\Gamma\cap Z$ is a lattice in $Z$ and $M=\{x\in Z:2x\in\Gamma$ is such that $M\Gamma$ is a lattice strictly containing $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The manifold $\Gamma_1/G$ is homeomorphic to $\Gamma_2/G$ implies that $\Gamma_1$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma_2$ since $G$ is $1$-connected and $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2$ are discrete, thus $\pi_1(\Gamma_1/G)=\Gamma_1$ and two homeomorphic manifolds have isomorphic fundamental groups. This implies that $\Gamma_1$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma_2$. In fact the converse is also true:  $\Gamma_1$ is isomorphic  to $\Gamma_2$, implies that $\Gamma_1/G$ is homeomorphic to $\Gamma_2/G$. This is a consequence of:

Raghunathan. Discrete subgroups of Lie  groups Corollary 2. p.34